# Las variables no pueden iniciar con underscore en python/django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Python, Django y MongoDB, apenas me voy inciando.

Estoy intentando cargar un template con esta información de usuarios, la consulta jala a la perfección:

```
{% if users %}
    <ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li><a href="/crawling/{{user._id}}"><b>{{user.nombre}}</b> {{user.ap_paterno}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No hay usuarios</p>
{% endif %}
```

Entonces bota el error:

> variables and attributes may not begin with underscores user._id

Y bueno, el ID viene de Mongo, el que te da por default, lo quiero para que cuando den click al usuario, vaya y busque a este usuario con una rapidez diabólica (por indexación) 
¿Cómo soluciono este error? ¿Necesitaré un ID adicional al que Mongo me da?

Ya para terminar y como plus, Si el dictionary `users` está vacío, sigue entrando al ciclo FOR intenté `if len( users ) < 0` pero me sacó un error de parsing.

Agradezco su apoyo

Comment: Puedes poner en el template algo como `href="/crawling/{{user_id}}"` y cuando desde django instances ese template le pasas `user_id=user._id`.

Comment: No entiendo, me puedes explicar un poco mejor porfa?

Comment: Olvidalo, perdona. Creia que `user` era un argumento que recibía el template, pero ahora que me fijo es un elemento de `users`, por lo que no se puede hacer lo que yo decía.

Comment: Mira a ver si te vale esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936601/django-templates-and-mongodb-id